# Sum and product problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, products

How can I find the result of:

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\prod\limits_{j=1}^{2} ij$

I know that $\prod\limits_{j=1}^{2} ij = 2i^2$, so I should simply do the summation as $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n2i^2$?

Comment: $$\frac{1}{3} n (n+1) (2 n+1)$$

Comment: yes, if you copied the problem correctly that seems pretty clear $\sum\limits_{i}^n (\prod\limits_{j=1}^2 ij) =\sum\limits_{i}^n (1j\cdot 2j)= \sum\limits_{i}^n (2j^2) = 2\sum_{i=1}^n i^2$ and you should be able know what that is.  ...  I guess I'm wondering how this rather strange expression came about in the first place.

Comment: One could generalize that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \prod\limits{j=1}^k ij =k! \sum\limits_{i=1}^n i^k$.... I guess.....  But writing something of the form $\prod\limits_j ij$ seems fairly weird to me. as that'd just be $\prod\limits_{j=1}^k ij = i^k \prod j = i^k k!$.

Answer (score 0):

This should be easy:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n 2i^2 = 2 \sum_{i=1}^n i^2 = 2 \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{3}$$